# reset key in dict python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a python dictionary.

```
project = {
             5:{"name:Mark"},
             1:{"name:Mark"},
             3:{"name:Mark"},
             4:{"name:Kim"},
             2:{"name:Kim"},
          }
```

I want to reset the keys.

```
project = {
             1:{"name:Mark"},
             2:{"name:Mark"},
             3:{"name:Mark"},
             4:{"name:Kim"},
             5:{"name:Kim"},
          }
```

How could I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by reset? Order is not a real property of a `dict`, this is just a representation. And this does change the key-value bindings, why? WHat's the logic?

Comment: What exactly in the logic that leads to #2 and #5 being swapped?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now that python has an ordered `dict` the key value pairs keep their order when you iterate over them. You just have to give the values new keys:

```py
project = {
             5:{"name:Mark"},
             1:{"name:Mark"},
             3:{"name:Mark"},
             4:{"name:Kim"},
             2:{"name:Kim"},
          }

project = {index:value for index,value in enumerate(project.values(), 1)}

print(project)
```

Output as requested.

(Note the short version given in the comment below:)

`project = dict(enumerate(project.values(), 1))`

Comment: Or `project = dict(enumerate(project.values(), 1))`